# Merge and trim videos from Google Photos?

Tags: video, google-photos

I would like to be able to merge and trim some videos which I have stored on Google Photos.

Would I have to download all the videos locally and then use some other video editing software?

Comment: I have removed the off-topic portions of your question.  Web app recommendations are off-topic here, but could potentially be asked at [softwarerecs.SE], but please check their Help Center for their requirements for questions before posting.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to download the video locally to edit. There is no edit or trim option for videos on Google Photos on computer.

You can try this on Google Photos mobile app, there you will get edit option to trim your video.